# função system() não aceita variável do tipo string em c++

Tags: array, c++, string, char

Afim de automatizar alguns backups que é preciso fazer rotineiramente, então pensei em utilizar um app em `dos` para fazer, porém estou com problemas na hora de compilar o executável porque me parece que a função `system()` só aceita variáveis do tipo char, o código que usei foi o seguinte.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {
string usuarios[5] = {"usuario","usuario","usuario","usuario","usuario"};
string diretorios[5];
string path[28];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    diretorios[i] = "mkdir c:\\backups\\"+usuarios[i];
    system(diretorios[i]);
    path[i] = "c:\\unisystem\\backup\\"+usuarios[i];
    system("exp system/abcd owner="+usuarios[i]+" file="+path[i]+"\\"+usuarios[i]+".dmp log="+path[i]+"\\"+usuarios[i]+".log compress=n");
}
cout << "O processo de backup terminou!"<< endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

há uma outra função que posso substituir a `system()` ou tenho que converter string em char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `system` não é uma função originária do C++ e sim da linguagem C, por isso recebe `const char*` e não `std::string`. A string do C++ nada mais é do que array de caracteres do C encapsulado numa classe, e tem um método que retorna um ponteiro pra esse array: `c_str()`

```
std::string texto = "Alguma coisa";
texto += " outra coisa";
std::system(texto.c_str());
```

Comment: Deu certo Obrigado! Mas então quer dizer que eu faço a referencia a informação da variavel texto pelo endereço da memoria que ela esta ocupando? Assim não preciso converter os tipos?

Comment: Não está convertendo, está apenas apontando. O ponteiro que `c_str()` retorna, representa sim o local onde os caracteres estão, mas quando você usa da forma em que eu mostrei, você tá "derreferenciando" ele, usando como uma string de C normal. Se quiser exibir o endereço de memória, aí sim teria que converter o ponteiro em si: `std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&minhaString[0]);`